# I'm having trouble showing up Messages.When I text, the message doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, firebase

I created AdapterChat like this:

AdapterChat:

```
public class AdapterChat  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterChat.MyHolder>{


    private static final int  MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    private static final int  MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

    Context context;
    List<ModelChat> chatList;
    String imageUrl;

    FirebaseUser fuser;

    public AdapterChat(Context context, List<ModelChat> chatList, String imageUrl){
        this.context = context;
        this.chatList = chatList;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        if (viewType==MSG_TYPE_RIGHT){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_chat_right, viewGroup, false);
            return new MyHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_chat_left, viewGroup, false);
            return new MyHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, final int position) {

        String message = chatList.get(position).getMeesage();
        String timeStamp = chatList.get(position).getTimestamp();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timeStamp));

        String dateTime = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyyy hh:mm aa", cal).toString();

        myHolder.messageTv.setText(message);
        myHolder.timeTv.setText(dateTime);

        try{
            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(myHolder.profileIv);
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
        if (position==chatList.size()-1){
            if (chatList.get(position).isSeen()){
                myHolder.isSeenTv.setText("Seen");
            } else {
                myHolder.isSeenTv.setText("Delivered");
            }

        } else {
            myHolder.isSeenTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(chatList.get(position).getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        } else {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }

    static class  MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView profileIv;
        TextView messageTv, timeTv, isSeenTv;

        public  MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            profileIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIv);
            messageTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTv);
            timeTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeTv);
            isSeenTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.isSeenTv);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have heard from a lot of people that the adapter has a problem but I checked again but did not find that problem, I tried a lot of ways but my problem cannot be changed, I need your help

Chats always don't have text, but on Firebase the chat has been updated

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you query the Realtime Database.